# npm install builds old version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have just build [my first npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth-hub-module). It is a small utility for helping me manage logins on hobby projects.

In v0.0.2 of this package I had an import that looked like this:

```
import { setRoute } from 'actions/route-actions';
```

Which did not work so i changed it to this

```
import { setRoute } from 'auth-hub-module/lib/actions/route-actions';
```

However when I try to install the new version (0.0.4) in my other projects I keep getting the import from version 0.0.2.

Why is this? How Can I debug this?

My build script works fine when I am in the package repo and the files being built there has the correct path.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package in the project with no luck.

Comment: 'npm install' builds whatever packages and versions are listed in package.json. Just to clarify what you're doing, are you running 'npm install myPackage' or just plain 'npm install'?

Comment: Tried both of them. The version it says it installs is what I expect. And the `package.json` in installed node module is the correct one but the lib is not updated.

Comment: I hate this suggestion, but it works more often for me than I like: have you tried uninstalling the offending package, running `npm cache clean`, and then reinstalling?